# Complex forms with Symfony - parent and child entities

Tags: php, symfony

I'm not quite sure if my title is informative enough.  If anyone with editing privileges wants to tweak it after reading this, feel free.

I need to create a form type that can mirror my current parent<->child, 1-to-1 relationship I have with my entities.  Right now, judging from the docs, the only way I can specify the child entity is to use the `Entity` form type, but that doesn't seem to give me what I want.  I don't want a selection of existing entities I can add to the parent.  I need to be able to fill in the fields of the parent, and then *optionally* fill in the fields of the child, all in the same form.  Ideally, I'd be able to do something like:

```
$builder->add('child', 'entity', array(
    'required' => false,
    'class' => 'MyBundle\Entity\Child',
    'type' => 'MyBundle\Form\Type\ChildType'
    )
);
```

But, from what I can see, the `type` option only exists with collections, which, again, is not what I'm dealing with.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if i get what you mean exactly but this should work:

```
$builder->add('child', 'child_type');
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html

**UPDATE**

```
class AddressType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('city','text');
        $builder->add('country','country');
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'my_address_form';
    }
}

class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name','text');
        $builder->add('address','my_address_form');
        //Or if you don't want to defined the child form as a service you can use
        //$builder->add('address', new AddressType());
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'my_user_form';
    }
}
```

in case if you need to define `AddressType` as a service:

```
services:
    acme_demo.form.type.address:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\Form\Type\AddressType
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: my_address_type }
```

Comment: I don't really see how.  I don't want to extend or build off the current entity field type, simply because I'm not dealing with a selection.  I'm trying to create/edit a `Parent`, and I want the ability to create/edit a `Child` that may be related to it in the same form.

Comment: I updated my answer, is it what you are looking for?